# How to setup latest eclipse for Android development?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just got the new **eclipse mars**:

> Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
>
> Build id: 20160218-0600

and the new **SDK manager**

> 24.4.1

**ADT** 23

I downloaded API 23 only for now. The problem is, no interface is showing up for the XML editor; I am getting this error at the bottom:

**This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in**

I have already got the latest ADT, as I downloaded it 15 minutes ago from scratch. How do I fix this without downloading and switching to a new API level? Also, what will be the difference between an API 23 interface (for the XML editor, of course) and an API 18 interface?

I tried Android Studio, but found it was too slow for my machine (a 3rd gen Intel i3 processor with 4 GB RAM).

Comment: If i upgrade the Android SDK tools to ver 25, it would let me  update ADT, but eclipse will force close on every launch. i have tried this atleast 6 times before. i need a proper guide

Comment: i chose 14 and it work, just wondering what is the difference?

Comment: if i make a new project with compile version 23 and another one with version 14, will they both have different interfaces

Comment: Eclipse is not really supported for Android development any more.  Google strongly urges people to move to Android Studio.  2.0 just released.